# maven/nexus JNI library release best practise?

Tags: maven, java-native-interface, pom.xml

Problem:

I release a maven package that contains a native JNI library inside. Because the native JNI library is not platform independent(unlike jar files), I now have to release my maven package under different package names, e.g. "my-maven-macos", "my-maven-debian", "my-maven-windows".

This is inconvenient for downstream users, who have to switch/juggle 3 different package names as their pom.xml dependency.

Is it possible, in this situation, to maintain a single maven package name? If not, what are the best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Create a single jar file with every native library and decide which one to extract and load **at run time** based on the OS you're running on.